# .Net client connecting to SQL 2005 with wrong provider

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a database on a server from a developer machine.  The server has the named pipes protocol disabled.  For some reason from one developer's box we get the following error message.  Two other developer boxes can connect using the same code just fine (using tcp/ip).  I have tried disabling The named pipes protocol on the client and still receive the following message.

> The client was unable to establish a
>   connection because of an error during
>   connection initialization process
>   before login. Possible causes include
>   the following:  the client tried to
>   connect to an unsupported version of
>   SQL Server; the server was too busy to
>   accept new connections; or there was a
>   resource limitation (insufficient
>   memory or maximum allowed connections)
>   on the server. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on
>   the other end of the pipe.)

The connection string being used:

data source=SERVER_NAME;database=DATABASE_NAME;trusted_connection=yes;Connection Timeout=120;

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

From Win98 clients and ADO, we used to force TCPIP on the connection by adding this to the connection string: Network Library=dbmssocn;

On XP, you can do the same with: Network Library=TCPIP;

Not sure if this is still supported or encouraged by M$ for ADO.Net connections.

Comment: think Network Library=DBMSSOCN; works for xp too. Also check if they have sql client tools installed as that can override a connection setting. If its sporadic; check their dhcp settings and network port speed negotiating settings on the network card settings as that has caused me database connection issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the command "CliConfg.exe" and set the default protocol to "TCP/IP"