# Why am I unable to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database from a MSTest harness in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio, mstest

Here is the problem I am facing. A few interesting tidbits...

Tests are built in MSTest originally in Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework 2.0 - I am able to debug the tests in order to walk into corners of code that are difficult to approach or prime with data.

We have since upgraded our systems to Visual Studio 2010 - (which incidentally forces the target framework to .NET 4 when the project contains tests only (hmmmm))

However when I attempt to debug a unit test with VS2010, the harness is unable to connect to our test database for any kind of code init or SQL commands to put the database in a known testable state (even plain jane SQL command + connection fails to connect w/o using any abstraction i.e. Application Blocks, configuration manager or Enterprise Library connection methods). I am presented with the following error...

> The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during 
>   connection initialization process before login.
>
> Possible causes include the following:
>   the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server;
>   the server was too busy to accept new connections; or there was a resource 
>   limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of 
>   the pipe.)

I realize that the most common response would be to ensure that Named Pipes and tcpip protocols are enabled on the remote DB instance. However A Sr. Dev on my team is able to happily connect to the DB while debugging a unit test, so I am leaning toward a local config/install/driver issue. In addition I am able to connect to localhost with out issue.

Further oddities - I am able to go to the toolbar, select "Test > Run > Tests in Current Context or Tests in Solution" and the complete regression test runs - no DB connectivity issues are experienced. However when using the short hand "Ctrl + R + T" (Which is the shorthand display next to the menu command) -  I am greeted with the above connection error whether debugging with a breakpoint or not.

I realize that the fact that I am debugging unit tests is debatable, however I find that it helps me during a dev cycle to take a TDD style approach, with the ability to step deep into code in certain conditions.

Again environment is VS2010, Windows 7, all .NET distros installed, SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2 installed.

If the facts and findings I have laid out even give you a sneaking suspicion, please let me know - I thank you all for your time!!

Comment: This answer looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889839/net-client-connecting-to-sql-2005-with-wrong-provider

Answer (score 1):

I have found a resolution, however it required a repair install of windows, and a build up of my dev environment. However I am finally back on track for this cycle.