# connecting to sql server, problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I just build my first web-application in asp.net that connects to a local database.
I got a weird problem.

The connection to the database works if i open the website BEFORE sql server after reboot. I can insert/read from the db from my webpage. But then sql server cant connect to the db. It looks like this then:

[image]

If i start sql server before the website then sql server works but the webpage doesnt work, visual studio then gives me this error:

[image]

Why are they interfering with each other and what can i do about it?
I use visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008 R2.

Comment: Is your database in [single-user mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx)?

Comment: would this help you at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889839/net-client-connecting-to-sql-2005-with-wrong-provider

Answer (score 1):

did you try to open your connection through server explorer from visual studio 2010 ? everytime you want to display the page in an web browser..just make sure you open the database connection through server explorer, it will work...no matter what was the order of your starting sql server.

Comment: It acts exactly the same way as the website, i.e. if I open sql server first server explorer cannot connect.